# OCMock: Mocking a method on a locally declared object

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, ocmock

I have been using OCMock to create stub and mocks. I'm struggling to mock a locally declared objects method though.

If I have the code below:

```
// Example.m 
#import "Object.h"

- (NSString *) methodWithLocallyDeclaredObject{

    Object *obj = [[Object alloc] init];
    NSString *string1 = [obj methodOnObject];
    NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"prepend %@", string1];

    return string2;
```

}

I want to be able to stub out the call to `methodOnObject` as it interacts with the filesystem and just return a string. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do with your code as-is. There are two things you can do to be able to test this case - use dependency injection, or a factory method.

**Option 1** - Dependency injection:

Change your method signature to require the object instead of creating it:

```
-(NSString *) methodWithObject:(Object*)obj
{
}
```

This method is preferred over option 2, but does not exactly fit the question you asked.

**Option 2** - Factory method:

Instead of creating your object inline, use a helper method to return it to you:

```
- (NSString *) methodWithLocallyDeclaredObject{

    Object *obj = [self newObject];
    NSString *string1 = [obj methodOnObject];
    NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"prepend %@", string1];

    return string2;
}

-(Object*)newObject
{
    return [[Object alloc] init];
}
```

then you can use a partial mock to mock out the `newObject` method and return something different.

```
id partiallyMockedObject = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:objectToTest];
[[[partiallyMockedObject expect] andReturn:yourMock] newObject];
```

So you are partially mocking the object you want to test (objectToTest) to return a stubbed implementation of your locally created object

Comment: Actually, you could stub the `+alloc` class method on `Object` and make that return a mock, on which you could then stub `methodOnObject`. I've not posted that as an answer because I think the two options presented in this answer are much preferrable.

Comment: Ahh ok, slightly annoying that it can't be done directly. I have a feeling I'll run into this situation a lot. What are your reasons for saying that stubbing the alloc class method isn't preferable? Option two is sensible and also really easy (thanks for that @michaels!) but I feel that my classes will be littered with helper methods that don't really add anything.

Comment: That's a big reason to use dependency injection - it makes your code much easier to test and avoids creating all this boilerplate.